# Restore the object's properties after applying in Blender 3D (apply location/rotation/scale)

Tags: blender

I've made a game map in blender and accidentally applied the objects transformations.
I don't really understand how it works. My guess is that the properties getting zeroed because the origin of the object is being set to its center.

I've tried the "clear origin" option, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?
Thank you,
    Amir.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that I understood you correctly:

Alt+R : Clear Rotation

Alt+G : Clear Location

Alt+S : Clear Scale

Answer (score 1):

When you have a complex object with a container and child transforms that hold the actual meshes, if you mistakenly Apply Location `CTRL+A` on your container (and it wasn't in the center) it will indeed annoyingly show the location gizmo for the object at the center of the scene (possibly with dotted lines pointing to the child origins).

To fix this (even if you applied location to the child transforms as well), Select  your meshes (for example with `B`) and Set Origin `CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+C` to Geometry. (This will fix locations of transforms with meshes.) 
Next either go to Edit mode `TAB` and select two (or more) of the extreme vertices - basically corners of the bounding box and Snap `SHIFT+S` Cursor to Selected (that should get your cursor to the very center of your collection). 
Next Unparent `ALT+P` your transforms (Clear and Keep Transformation), Select your original parent container and Snap `SHIFT+S` Selection to Cursor. 
Finally Select the children again and Parent `CTRL+P` them back to the container (by Selecting it last).

In the case of Scale and Rotation, if the Undo `CTRL+Z` didn't help you, then you'll need to manually adjust them back to how they used to be. Point of reference usually helps, if you've got a backup of a previous version, you can just compare to that. Otherwise you can create basic Cube Mesh `SHIFT+A` or use the grid and Ruler/Protractor (Tool Shelf `T` > Grease Pencil > Ruler/Protractor) to help you (notice the helpful `CTRL` guidance).

For Scale `S`, measure against known length (measured changed length / measured original length), divide the Scale (Properties > Object > Scale) by the resulting quotient and apply the result as new Scale. (Notice, that if you didn't change the Scale uniformly, you might need to do this separately for each axis.)

For Rotation `R` you'll need to do similar measurements and calculations, though simple manual adjustment with the help of `CTRL` might get you desired results.

After you've corrected Scale and Rotation, remember to Apply `CTRL+A` your result (but preferably not the Position).

Answer (score 0):

Once you apply transformation to the object data, there is no way to get it back automatically since its a destructive operation *(like flattening layers of an image or scaling it down)*.

Besides manually setting to the cursor and making that the origin, but that still misses rotation and scale.

you can use Origin tool with 'Origin To Geometry' option to reset the pivot, but thats all.

Comment: You can juggle around with 3D cursor to remember origin position, then reset and move back to the cursor.

Comment: That only works for location, not rotation or scale.

Comment: That's correct, the other two need manual adjustment. I guess might as well expand the answer. Original point was that you can try and cancel the application on the Scale and Rotation, but for some reason that does not always work with Position.